# Excel Formula: Minimum value of an array containing strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Example:

=MIN({"510";"515";"503";"";"";""})

How to get the min value of this array from **non-empty** items. Item *503* to be the minimum here and is the answer.

Comment: Will it only ever contain number values as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try-

```
=MIN(IFERROR(--{"510","515","503","","",""},""))
```

`--` enforce strings to convert numbers if they are digits only. IFERROR will convert errors for empty string to nulls so that MIN function ignore those.

***Note:*** comma `,` and semicolon `;` depends on regional settings.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your string will only contain number, you could do:

```
=MIN(NUMBERVALUE(A1:E1))
```